# An example from Java a Beginner's guide, 5th Edition

Tags: java

I have an example from Java, A Beginner's Guide, 5th Edition but when I run it gives several errors. How can I change this so that it works?

```
public class ForTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws java.io.IOException {
        int i;
        System.out.println("press s to stop");

        if(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 's'; i++)
            System.out.println("pass # " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by reading the error messages. If that code is really in the 5th edition of a book, I wonder how bad were the 4 first editions.

Comment: Yeah... reading the error messages and posting them here, @Sempliciotto.

Comment: Sorry, it was a for not if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 's'; i++)
        System.out.println("pass # " + i);
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `for(...)` instead of `if(...)`.So change

```
if(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 's'; i++)
```

to

```
for(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 's'; i++)
```